# Setting 'src' of img tag dynamically using backbone templating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set the `src` of `img` tag dynamically with backbone templating, but `/` is appended automatically for which `img` not loaded.The part of template looks like -

```
<script type="text/template" id="home">
.......
<% var d=names[0].get("image_link")+".jpg" 
//d=d.substring(0 , d.length-1); tried to cut down last char
%>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive ui-corner-all"  width="100%" height="auto" src=<%=d%> /> 
.......
</script>
```

The output -

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive ui-corner-all"  width="100%" height="auto" src="image1.jpg/" />
```

I couldn't figure it out how to exclude that `/` in `img` src. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That slash is actually there in the code. As you don't have any quotation marks around the attribute value, the `/` in `/>` becomes part of the value.

Add quotation marks:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive ui-corner-all"  width="100%" height="auto" src="<%=d%>" />
```